# How can I format columns without using Perl's format?

Tags: perl, formatting

Often in Perl I want to print out column/row data, say, from a hash.

This is simple:

```
foreach my $k(keys %h)
{
  print $k, "\t", $h{$k}, "\n";
}
```

However, if the key happens to have a **varying** length, then the formatting just looks **very** jagged. I've investigated [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html), and it's typically too heavyweight for what I'm looking for, which is a 'simple' column-row aligning pretty-printer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you'll find [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) useful. Here is a small example:

```
printf("%10s\t%10s\n", $k, $h{$k});
## prints "         key\t         value\n"
## prints "  longer_key\t  longer_value\n"
```

Long values are not truncated, and you can change text alignment inside the block:

- `%10s` - means string type of length 10 (left aligned)
- `%-10s` - means string type of length 10 (right aligned)

A full list of formats is on the [`sprintf` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 7):

Check out the `x` operator (documented at [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)), useful for simple formatting tasks that involve padding fields to a specific length:

```
while ((my $key, $value) = each %h)
{
    print $key . (" " x (20 - length $key)) . $value, "\n";
}
```

You can also use `sprintf` or `printf` ([perldoc -f sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), [perldoc -f printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)) (with these you can also pad with zeros in numbers):

```
while ((my $key, $value) = each %h)
{
    printf("%20s %20s\n", $key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The robust solution requires two passes: one to determine the length of the longest key, the other to print the output:

```
my $l = 0;
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    $l = length($key) if length($key) > $l;
}

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    printf "%-${l}s  %s\n", $key, $hash{$key};
}
```

If you know the upper limit of the key lengths ahead of time, you can avoid the first loop.

Comment: use List::Util qw(max); my $l = max( map {length} keys %hash );

Answer (score 5):

If you want a heavy-duty solution, there are modules like [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Table).

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not an optimal solution, but you'll need to find your maximum key and maximum value lengths, and then pass them to either [sprintf()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#sprintf-FORMAT%2C-LIST) or [pack()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#pack-TEMPLATE%2CLIST).

Or you could use static maximum lengths if your data source has "reasonable" constraints (for example, column length limits in a database, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said format might be too heavy-weight, but it might actually be less complex. Try something like this:

```
foreach my $k(keys %h) {
  format =
  Key:  @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Value:  @>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  $k,                     $h{$k}
  .

  write;
}
```